# SQL Server collate error in query

Tags: sql-server

I've looked all over for help on this but nothing seems to be working.

I have the following statement in an SP that fails with the collate error each time:

```
INSERT INTO #TableR (id, email, forename, Age, gender) 
SELECT TOP 1 #TEMPMDUK.id AS [id], email, forename, Age, gender 
  FROM #TEMPMDUK 
 WHERE SUBSTRING(postcode, 0, (CHARINDEX(' ', postcode, 0)+2)) in  (select Postcode from LiveTable) 
   and not #TEMPMDUK.ID in (SELECT id FROM #Excludelist) 
   and #TEMPMDUK.ID in (SELECT id FROM #Includelist) 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

It only started to happen after we added the following clause to the statement:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(postcode, 0, (CHARINDEX(' ', postcode, 0)+2)) in  (select Postcode from LiveTable)
```

If we run this as a clause in a select statement everything is fine but when we put it into the INSERT statement in the SP it breaks.

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Should it be .... AND #TEMPMDUK.ID NOT IN(SELECT id FROM #Excludelist)....

Comment: Might be that you need to CONVERT to INT that whole substring.Assuming Postcode is numeric.

Comment: paste exact error message

Comment: Sorry, this is the message that we're getting:Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure email D6605 Suzuki Celerio, Line 103
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know your table structures but it seems that you have different collations in columns. Try playing with

```
SELECT TOP 1 #TEMPMDUK.id AS [id], email COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, forename, Age, gender
```

Or

```
SELECT TOP 1 #TEMPMDUK.id AS [id], email COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, forename, Age, gender
```